# IBOutlets in Nib are nil on both awakeFromNib and initWithCoder – no subviews

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, interface-builder

I have a custom UIView subclass with three subviews added to it via Nib file (a UIImageView, a UIView and a UITextField) and IBOutlets set. But when the `awakeFromNib` or `initWithCoder` get called in the subclass then all IBOutlets are `nil` and even the subviews array is **empty**.

I'm using Swift and XCode 6 beta 5 where this UIView **subclass is in a framework** and I added the UIView subclass to a Storyboard within my project so I can use the new **Live View** technology. But I can't see the added subviews in the Live View either which is very sad.

I couldn't find any way to fix this, here's the code from my UIView subclass:

```
import UIKit

@IBDesignable public class BlurredSheetEntryView: UIView {

    @IBOutlet var iconImageView: UIImageView?
    @IBOutlet var separatorView: UIView?
    @IBOutlet public var textField: UITextField?

    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)
    }

    required public init(coder aDecoder: NSCoder!) {
        super.init(coder: aDecoder)

        for subView in self.subviews {
            println("subView: \(subView)")
        }

        println("self.textField: \(self.textField)")
        println("self.iconImageView: \(self.iconImageView)")
        println("self.separatorView: \(self.separatorView)")
    }

    override public func awakeFromNib() {

        for subView in self.subviews {
            println("subView: \(subView)")
        }

        println("self.textField: \(self.textField)")
        println("self.iconImageView: \(self.iconImageView)")
        println("self.separatorView: \(self.separatorView)")

    }
}
```

And my Nib file looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<document type="com.apple.InterfaceBuilder3.CocoaTouch.XIB" version="3.0" toolsVersion="6205" systemVersion="14A314h" targetRuntime="iOS.CocoaTouch" propertyAccessControl="none" useAutolayout="YES" useTraitCollections="YES">
    <dependencies>
        <plugIn identifier="com.apple.InterfaceBuilder.IBCocoaTouchPlugin" version="6198"/>
        <capability name="Aspect ratio constraints" minToolsVersion="5.1"/>
    </dependencies>
    <objects>
        <placeholder placeholderIdentifier="IBFilesOwner" id="-1" userLabel="File's Owner"/>
        <placeholder placeholderIdentifier="IBFirstResponder" id="-2" customClass="UIResponder"/>
        <view contentMode="scaleToFill" id="iN0-l3-epB" customClass="BlurredSheetEntryView" customModule="BlurredSheetEntry" customModuleProvider="target">
            <rect key="frame" x="0.0" y="0.0" width="300" height="50"/>
            <autoresizingMask key="autoresizingMask" widthSizable="YES" heightSizable="YES"/>
            <subviews>
                <imageView userInteractionEnabled="NO" contentMode="scaleToFill" horizontalHuggingPriority="251" verticalHuggingPriority="251" translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints="NO" id="ZnN-gy-Mc6">
                    <rect key="frame" x="8" y="5" width="40" height="40"/>
                    <constraints>
                        <constraint firstAttribute="width" secondItem="ZnN-gy-Mc6" secondAttribute="height" multiplier="1:1" id="C4N-zC-woh"/>
                    </constraints>
                </imageView>
                <textField opaque="NO" clipsSubviews="YES" contentMode="scaleToFill" contentHorizontalAlignment="left" contentVerticalAlignment="center" placeholder="Placeholder" minimumFontSize="17" clearButtonMode="whileEditing" translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints="NO" id="npg-xI-NSo">
                    <rect key="frame" x="66" y="8" width="226" height="34"/>
                    <fontDescription key="fontDescription" type="system" pointSize="15"/>
                    <textInputTraits key="textInputTraits"/>
                </textField>
                <view contentMode="scaleToFill" translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints="NO" id="8lA-9y-yoA">
                    <rect key="frame" x="56" y="5" width="2" height="40"/>
                    <color key="backgroundColor" white="0.66666666666666663" alpha="1" colorSpace="calibratedWhite"/>
                    <constraints>
                        <constraint firstAttribute="width" constant="2" id="QgG-pW-8q0"/>
                    </constraints>
                </view>
            </subviews>
            <color key="backgroundColor" white="1" alpha="1" colorSpace="custom" customColorSpace="calibratedWhite"/>
            <constraints>
                <constraint firstAttribute="bottom" secondItem="8lA-9y-yoA" secondAttribute="bottom" constant="5" id="51o-Il-vGA"/>
                <constraint firstItem="8lA-9y-yoA" firstAttribute="leading" secondItem="ZnN-gy-Mc6" secondAttribute="trailing" constant="8" id="AEG-I2-vsT"/>
                <constraint firstAttribute="bottom" secondItem="npg-xI-NSo" secondAttribute="bottom" constant="8" id="E0H-fN-lg4"/>
                <constraint firstItem="8lA-9y-yoA" firstAttribute="top" secondItem="iN0-l3-epB" secondAttribute="top" constant="5" id="EYR-L8-96J"/>
                <constraint firstAttribute="bottom" secondItem="ZnN-gy-Mc6" secondAttribute="bottom" constant="5" id="GFW-R2-jGI"/>
                <constraint firstAttribute="trailing" secondItem="npg-xI-NSo" secondAttribute="trailing" constant="8" id="Lws-lv-n37"/>
                <constraint firstItem="ZnN-gy-Mc6" firstAttribute="top" secondItem="iN0-l3-epB" secondAttribute="top" constant="5" id="Pv0-ZV-aT4"/>
                <constraint firstItem="ZnN-gy-Mc6" firstAttribute="leading" secondItem="iN0-l3-epB" secondAttribute="leading" constant="8" id="XOI-jO-Sv7"/>
                <constraint firstItem="npg-xI-NSo" firstAttribute="top" secondItem="iN0-l3-epB" secondAttribute="top" constant="8" id="dA3-Wg-XfN"/>
                <constraint firstItem="npg-xI-NSo" firstAttribute="leading" secondItem="8lA-9y-yoA" secondAttribute="trailing" constant="8" id="mq6-6r-Z2b"/>
            </constraints>
            <nil key="simulatedStatusBarMetrics"/>
            <freeformSimulatedSizeMetrics key="simulatedDestinationMetrics"/>
            <connections>
                <outlet property="iconImageView" destination="ZnN-gy-Mc6" id="0Hp-sr-mqx"/>
                <outlet property="separatorView" destination="8lA-9y-yoA" id="VFx-En-K3c"/>
                <outlet property="textField" destination="npg-xI-NSo" id="tIy-N2-g2j"/>
            </connections>
            <point key="canvasLocation" x="371" y="327"/>
        </view>
    </objects>
</document>
```

**UPDATE:**
I've created an absolutely simple example project where I only did the following:

- choose Master-View template for iOS
- add new Framework called "MyCustomTableViewCell" with Xib file
- add a UIView with blue background color as a subview in Xib file
- add @IBOutlet and connection in the Swift file
- add a println() statement within awakeFromNib() in Swift file
- set the class of Cells in the Master tableView to the subclass from the framework

When I build & run and click the "+"-Sign on the top right corner, I get "nil" printed out on the console as a result for the @IBOutlet.
This is my issue and what annoys me. But maybe I'm doing something wrong here ...

I've uploaded the example project, here's the download url:
https://www.dropbox.com/s/vcb0sa98tw6i1iv/NilObjectsFromXib.zip?dl=0

I'm using a framework because I have to as I want to see my subclass as a Live View in my Main storyboard.

Thanks for any help in advance! :)

Comment: How are you creating the instance of `BlurredSheetEntryView`?

Comment: I'm creating it by adding it as a subview to a Storyboard.

Comment: Btw: This still happens with XCode 6 Beta 6 and I filed a bug with Apple right after this post here. (17957402) Hope they will fix it soon. Does anyone know a workaround?

Comment: I've updated my question with an example project, where you can see the issue when you click on the "+" on the top right corner and have a look at the console.

Comment: @Dschee could you attach a link to this open radar issue? I can not find it so maybe it was removed or something.

Comment: I have not posted it via Open Radar, but the bug report is still open. I posted the number in case someone gets a "duplicate of" message from Apple to check if it's the same. I re-created my project in the mean time and don't have this issue any more. But I can't tell why ... maybe it is fixed, maybe I did something different on the second try.

Answer (score -1):

I reviewed your project and:
You need to add your XIB file to `Copy bundle resourses` in project settings

You need to register custom cell XIB for using in your table view via:

```
 override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        self.tableView.registerNib(UINib(nibName:"MyCustomTableViewCell", bundle: nil), forCellReuseIdentifier: "CustomCell")
    }
```

Then you can use your custom cell in your table:

```
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("CustomCell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as MyCustomTableViewCell

    // Do something with your cell

    return cell
}
```

Comment: The thing is that the purpose of creating a custom UIView in a framework is to see it live rendered within Interface Builder. So adding those programmatically isn't the right solution for this question. Adding the XIB from the framework to the `Copy bundle resources' didn't help.

Comment: @Dschee but how you table view can view cell, if you don't setup table for it? Your custom cell's function `awakeFromNib` will be never fired, because you don't create any cell object!